# How to get app url in Marmalade 6.3 like HandleOpenURL in Objective c?

Tags: iphone, macos, marmalade, marmalade-edk

We have a Game app developed in Marmalade 6.3 version.
We got Xcode build for that using Mkb file and able to deploy it successfully on iPhone.
We are launching this Game app from one another app developed in Xcode, and append some text like credentials in url as well. But not finding any way to get App URL in marmalade generated Xcode project in game app.

Is there any way to get this?
We have tried S3eEDK but it's importing UIKIT framework and that is not supported in game app as it's Developed using Mac OSX.

Thanks & Regards..

Comment: Your question is not clear to me? Why you can't use EDK to achieve this? Why UIKit is not supported in your game app? UIKit is a basic framework in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

As the game is developed in macOSX we are not having even appdelegate class in our app. And having appkit in place of UIkit but once we add that to our app it gives error no such file or directory....